# captureEntirePageScreenshot with dynamic name in Selenese

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I want to generate the filename parameter of the captureEntirePageScreenshot command in Selenese through javascript. Is that possible?

The scenario is that I want to take a screenshot of every page that is opened, and the name of the webpage is generated dynamically and encodes some information.

Comment: you can give file name as "fileName"+count; here count is a variable you have to increment it for every screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by using the "storeEval" command to generate the name, followed by the original "captureEntirePageScreenshot" command that uses the variable defined in "storeEval" as the parameter.

I hope it saves someone 30 mins :)

Answer (score 1):

Combine it in javascript:

```
    <tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>Date.now()</td>
    <td>timestamp</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>&quot;SomePrefixScreenShot&quot; + storedVars['timestamp']</td>
    <td>filename</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${filename}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```